# How to change tag to id in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

This sounds very basic, I'm new with Javascript. I have this code that changes the word color to colour if the language is set to British English.

```
<h1>Color</h1>
<script>
    if (navigator.language == 'en-GB') {
        var h1 = document.body.getElementsByTagName('h1');
        for (var i = 0; i < h1.length; ++i)
        h1[i].innerHTML = h1[i].innerHTML.replace('Color', 'Colour');
    }
</script>
```

It's currently set for the tag "h1", how can I change it so I can use ids?

Comment: You would want to use class instead of id because using id you will get only first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, add an `ID` attribute to your element:

```
<h1 id="myHeader">Color</h1>
```

Second, use `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElementsByTagName`:

```
var h1 = document.getElementById('myHeader');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to be changing the text in multiple places you don't want to be using ID. IDs are unique, and only one element on a page should have a given ID.

Depending on your situation, you might want to use classes, and either [`.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) or [`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```js
var langs = document.querySelectorAll('.lang');

for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; i++) {
  var html = langs[i].innerHTML;
  langs[i].innerHTML = html.replace(/(C|c)olor/, '$1olour');
}
```

```html
<h1 class="lang">Color</h1>

<p class="lang">My favourite color is pink.</p>
```